# List unique line items and their daily counts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, smart-listing

In my rails app, new line items are created daily. I need to be able to have my smart_listing show how many apples and oranges were ordered. For instance:

- Line Item     QTY
- Apple          2
- Orange         1

What I am getting is:

- Line Item    QTY
- Apple        1
- Apple        1
- Orange       1

  ```
  line_item_scope = LineItem.all
  line_item_scope = line_item_scope.where(created_at: Date.today.beginning_of_day..Date.today.end_of_day)

  if customer_signed_in?
    line_item_scope = line_item_scope.ticket.customer(current_customer.id)
  end

  @line_items = smart_listing_create(:line_items, line_item_scope, partial: "line_items/listing2", default_sort: {updated_at: "desc"})
  ```

My initial thought was to create a .map(&:name).uniq but that returns an array when I need a relationship to go into the smart listing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to display just `LineItem`'s `name` and the number of items of that name, then `group` method can help:

```
line_item_scope.group(:name).count
```

This will construct a hash:

`result = { "Apple" => 2, "Orange" => 1 }`

Then this hash can be iterated to display the values:

```
result.each do |name, count|
...
end
```

Or the number of line items can be selected as a column:

```
line_items_scope =
  LineItem.group(:name)
    .order(:name)
    .select("name, COUNT(*) as count")
```

Then `line_items_scope` can be fed to `smart_listing_create` as a `ActiveRecordRelation`

Comment: This would work, but I don't know how to put it into smart_listing which only accepts ActiveRecordsRelations or possibly arrays. Would it be appropriate to: `...collection.select("DISTINCT name").each do |line_item|` then create a model level which reports out how many were created that day?     `def created_today
        created_today = LineItem.all
        created_today = created_today.where(created_at: Date.today.beginning_of_day..Date.today.end_of_day)
        created_today = created_today.where(:name => self.name).count
        created_today
    end`

Comment: `count` can be selected into every model of `ActiveRecordRelation`. I updated my answer, hope it helps